# std::priority_queue complex types?

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, std, priority-queue

I want to use a std::priority_queue with complex types:

```
typedef struct
{
uint8_t data;
    uint64_t moredata;
}myData;

typedef struct
{
    boost::mutex someQueueLock;
    std::priority_queue<myData> myQueue; //does not work
}
```

I don't want to use a queue full of pointers (priority_queue) because the pointers can get invalid.

Is this even possible? Or should I use another std container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) uses `operator<` to sort elements by default, it requires elements to be **strict weak ordered**

You need to define `operator<` function for `myData` type

```
bool operator<(const myData& lhs, const myData& rhs)
{
    return lhs.data < rhs.data;
}
```

§ 23.6.4.1
 Class template priority_queue

> Any sequence container with random access iterator and supporting operations front(), push_back() and pop_back() can be used to instantiate priority_queue. In particular, vector (23.3.6) and deque (23.3.3) can be used. Instantiating priority_queue also involves supplying a function or function object for mak- ing priority comparisons; the library assumes that the function or function object defines a **strict weak ordering** (25.4).

§ 25.4

> All the operations in 25.4 have two versions: one **that takes a function object of type Compare and one that uses an operator<.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your own comparison function, so that the priority_queue will know which items have higher priority.

```
bool MyCompare(const myData& left, const myData& right)
{
    // todo: return true if left has higher priority than right
}

std::priority_queue<myData, std::vector<myData>, MyCompare> queue;
```